# JasperReports with XML as input --- Getiing Inputstream null pointer exception

Tags: java, xml, pointers, null, jasper-reports

I am using iReport-4.1.1 to create the .jasper and .jrxml FILES. My files are under Webcontent/reports

Below is the code that I am using to open a PDF from jasper. I am passing XML as the input.

```
InputStream reportStream = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/reports/FUECReport.jasper");
JRXmlDataSource xmlDataSource = new JRXmlDataSource(stringToDom(xmlResult));

HashMap parameterMap = new HashMap();
parameterMap.put("TITLE_MSG_PARAM", fUECRptMsg);
parameterMap.put("SURVEY_YEAR_PARAM", surveyYear);              
parameterMap.put("STATE_CODE_PARAM", fipsStateCode);

JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream,servletOutputStream, parameterMap,xmlDataSource);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
servletOutputStream.flush();
servletOutputStream.close();

//this is the function that is converting the xmlsource to Document
public static Document stringToDom(String xmlSource)  throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException { 
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource)));  
}
```

When I ran, I get a null pointer exception in the line:

```
JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(*reportStream*,servletOutputStream, parameterMap,xmlDataSource);
```

saying reportStream is null

Anybody please let me know where the problem is.

When I run and compile from ireport, I am successfully able to open the PDF.

Thanks

GK

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should check the path to the report template in line:

```
InputStream reportStream = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/reports/FUECReport.jasper");
```

May be you should change path to *`/WEB-INF/reports/FUECReport.jasper`*? You can try to check the file availability with help of `java.io`.

On the second, the variable `reportStream` must contains the *`compiled`* report.

The [javadoc](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperRunManager.html#runReportToPdfFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map,%20net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource%29) does not say it for this method (you can read about parameters for the same method with [another signature](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperRunManager.html#runReportToPdfStream%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.util.Map%29)), but you can view the source code of this method:

runReportToPdfStream

```
public static void JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(java.io.InputStream inputStream,
                                    java.io.OutputStream outputStream,
                                    java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> parameters,
                                    JRDataSource jrDataSource)
                             throws JRException
                           throws JRException
```

> - Fills a report and sends it directly to an OutputStream in PDF format. The intermediate JasperPrint object is not saved on disk.

Please, check your datasource - prepare another datasource and pass it to `runReportToPdfStream` method.

You can use [JRMapArrayDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRMapArrayDataSource.html), the sample of `JRMapArrayDataSource` using:

```
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("Title", "Report title");

        Map<String, String> firstRow = new HashMap<String, String>();
        firstRow.put("title", "Greatest Hits");
        firstRow.put("artist", "Dolly Parton");
        firstRow.put("country", "USA");
        firstRow.put("company", "RCA");
        firstRow.put("price", "9.90");
        firstRow.put("year", "1982");

        Map<String, String> secondRow = new HashMap<String, String>();
        secondRow.put("title", "Still got the blues");
        secondRow.put("artist", "Gary Moore");
        secondRow.put("country", "UK");
        secondRow.put("company", "Virgin records");
        secondRow.put("price", "10.20");
        secondRow.put("year", "1990");

        Object[] data = {firstRow, secondRow};

        JRMapArrayDataSource dataSource = new JRMapArrayDataSource(data);

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, targetFileName);
```

If everything will be OK, the problem in method you preparing dataSource.

Comment: The FUECReport.jasper file is in right location. I changed the InputStream object from reportStream to reportStream1. I also used the InputStreamReader to check if the inputstream is correct. It is correct,I checked. And now I get an exception, net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from InputStream    ........ Caused by: java.io.EOFException

Comment: I was able to overcome this issue, but now the PDF gets open(FROM runReportToPdfStream) with all the values as NULL. I don't see any data in the PDF. All values to the column are NULL.

Comment: Did you check parameters map? Did you see static text?

Comment: I am passing parameters parameterMap.put("TITLE_MSG_PARAM", fUECRptMsg); parameterMap.put("SURVEY_YEAR_PARAM", surveyYear);               parameterMap.put("STATE_CODE_PARAM", fipsStateCode); AND the XMLDOCUMENT as xmlDataSource. I saw the static text, i;e column names on the PDF

Comment: Yes, I can see a static text. I just added a dummy title and it displays.

Comment: The sample: http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/datasource/index.html

Comment: Yes, I created the datasource manually. I am using JRXmlDataSource that takes Document as a contructor parameter. JRDataSource xmlDataSource = new JRXmlDataSource(stringToDom(xmlResult)); DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder(); document=builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource))); } where xmlSource is the XML

Comment: Yeah, but I think it will be better if you try to prepare datasource based on JRTableModelDataSource, for example. It would be a check of your datasource preparation. You can use snippet from this link: http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/datasource/index.html.  It will be a test of your report template

Comment: ok, I will see if I can use JRTableModelDatasource to build my datasource and update the result. Thanks

Comment: Also while using the JRTableModelDataSource, do we need to pass my XML RESULT

Comment: Alex,Once I convert the XML to document object, I again tried to parse the document object to get the XML back. And I get the correct XML which I am passing. So I feel there is no problem in stringToDom method that is converting into DOCUMENT the given XML. But still we have the same error, null values on PDF. To use this JRTableModelDataSource I am not sure how to pass to "private Object[][] data" in the class that is available in the link provided by you.

Comment: @user1015388 Add sample how to use JRMapArrayDataSource